# Burley trailer hitch noise

Tags: touring, noise, trailer

We tow a Burley Nomad trailer behind our tandem. Love the trailer, but the hitch rattles and makes enough noise to be annoying. Grease or chain lube quiets it temporarily, but not for long. Does anyone have a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: In a [review by Alex Wetmore](http://phred.org/~alex/bikes/burleynomad.html) he did not like the hitch at all.